# How a reentrancy attack can occur

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a smartcontract here which allows  users to deposit 1 eth per block, and withdraw their deposits in a future date. Is there any reentrancy attack going on here. Can some one point it out to me. Thank you

```
contract TestContract{
    uint256 immutable DEPOSIT_LIMIT_PER_BLOCK = 1 ether;                            

    struct UserDeposit {
        uint256 balance;
        uint256 blockDeposited;
    }
    mapping(address => UserDeposit) public allDeposits;

    constructor() public {}

    receive() external payable {
        require(msg.value <= DEPOSIT_LIMIT_PER_BLOCK, "TOO_MUCH_ETH");

        UserDeposit storage last= allDeposits[tx.origin];

        uint256 maxDeposit = last.blockDeposited == block.number
            ? DEPOSIT_LIMIT_PER_BLOCK - last.balance
            : DEPOSIT_LIMIT_PER_BLOCK;

        if(msg.value > maxDeposit) {
            // refund user if they are above the max deposit allowed
            uint256 refundValue = msg.value - maxDeposit ;                        
            
            (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{value: refundValue}("");
            require(success, "ETH_TRANSFER_FAIL");
            
            last.balance -= refundValue;                                             
        }

        last.balance += msg.value;
        last.blockDeposited = block.number;
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 val) external {
        UserDeposit storage last= allDeposits[tx.origin];
        require(last.balance >= val, "NOT_ENOUGH_ETH");

        last.balance -= val;
        
        (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{value: val}("");
        require(success, "ETH_TRANSFER_FAIL");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using some times tx.origin and other msg.sender? At least it is inconsistent. Having `last.balance -= refundValue;` before `last.balance += msg.value;` smells to problems. You should learn about the Check-Effects-Interactions pattern https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/checks_effects_interactions.html.

Comment: @Ismael why does `last.balance -= refundValue;`before `last.balance += msg.value;` smells trouble. Can you please explain that further. Thanks

Comment: In solc 0.7 and older it will cause an overflow.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for that. I understood. One more small question. Is there any way to reduce gas price spent on receive function. Do you see any obvious changes I could do. I really appreciate the help

Comment: The more expensive operations are modifying storage and probably sending ether back when it is above the maxDeposit. Sorry, but after a quick look I haven't found changes that might reduce gas usage.

Answer (score 0):

`last.balance += msg.value;` must come before transaction success otherwise attacker might steal the more eth than required by running loop as his balance is not updated.